# iOS : how to fill a field if user gets a text message from our service?

Tags: ios, message

One way to log in in our app is to fill a phone number, which sends a SMS with a key to this phone number.

I want to know if there is a way to check if the current user's phone number is the same than the one typed, and if so automatically fill the field so the user doesn't have to fill it himself, and even worse leave the app to fetch it in Messages if needed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish this , server sends verification to the number that the user had typed with AccoountKit or any other service  , get sms and type it , as there is no permission in IOS to make the app intercept user messages

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. That's actually what I thought about intercepting user messages, but is there a way to get the user's phone number? I guess not.

Comment: Also you can't it may be all theses in Android but not IOS , Apple restricts such permissions except if you use jailbroken device

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thanks for the answer!